# moving from eclipse to intellij with spring boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I just moved from eclipse to IntelliJ. 
I have a spring boot project, that runs perfectly in eclipse. but when I tried to run it on IntelliJ, I'm getting "Process finished with exit code 1"
I've tried all the next solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+intellij+spring+boot

but nothing workes. any advice? 
[spring boot config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdgqu.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you've done and how your process is launching (e.g. the command line that was used)?

Comment: Hi @nitind, 
edit configurations -> add spring boot ->main class: my project main class. vm options: copied from  VM arguments (eclipse) and changed them as needed.

Comment: I've added an image to the question of spring bot configurations

Comment: What does the console output say?

Comment: Hi, 
I can not post all console output:
this is the end of it, is it ok?
SLF4J: A number (170) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are
SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your application is failing on startup, probably due to missing configuration.

Put your correct spring boot profile in "active profiles".

For example, this might be "dev" or "dev,integration-tests" or whatever :)

Comment: I've added my active profile. still getting "Process finished with exit code 1 "

Comment: What does your program do? Is it designed to keep running? Or does it exit normally? What does the log / console say

Comment: It's designed to keep running.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the problem by deleting the contents of the folder .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin.
and reimport maven projects.